# PHP Laravel - Best practice to run controller with variable from command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am trying to setup a command in Laravel, that should run every day at 18:30.

I have a function in a controller, I wish to run (is this the correct place to put a function that should only be run from the command line?):

`ReportController.php`:

```
public function process($reportName)
{
   return("Function process has run correctly. Report: ".$reportName." ");
}
```

I have created a command file:

`ProcessReports.php`

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Http\Controllers\ReportController;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ProcessReports extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'report:process {reportName}';
    protected $description = 'Process reports from FTP server';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        $ReportController = new ReportController(); 
        $ReportController->process($reportName);      
    }
}
```

Furthermore, in my `Kernel.php` I have registered my command:

`Kernel.php`:

```
 protected $commands = [
            'App\Console\Commands\ProcessReports',
 ];

 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
 {
    $schedule->command('report:process MyReport')
               ->dailyAt('18:30');                        
 }
```

I then try to run my command like: `$ php artisan report:process MyReport`. But this is not possible. It gives me this error:

> Undefined variable: **reportName**

Can anyone guide me on how to create commands, which can run my function daily?

Comment: You'd need to get the parameter first in your `handle()`, something like `$reportName = $this->argument('reportName');` [Artisan Command I/O](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#command-io)

Comment: But I wish to dynamically be able to set my `reportName` in my Kernel file. So I can use it like: `$schedule->command('report:process MyReport')->dailyAt('18:30')`

Comment: I guess you can still do that. As of now, no matter what you type as parameter will not be recognized. `protected $signature = 'report:process {reportName}';` will not handle the parameter, this is just to show a list of command parameters when you type the command without params.

Comment: The second parameter of the schedule's command method is an array of parameters for the command that you are calling.

`$schedule->command('report:process', ['reportName' => 'my-report'])->daily();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the argument first, change your `handle()` method to:

```
public function handle()
{
    //
    $reportName = $this->argument('reportName');
    $ReportController = new ReportController(); 
    $ReportController->process($reportName);      
}
```

Documentation: [Artisan Command I/O](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#command-io)